# How do I know what new packages have been added to the Raspberry Pi OS image?

Tags: raspbian-buster, packages

I'm brand new to Raspberry Pi. I ordered a Raspberry Pi 4 and it arrived today. Looking about I found the page on the RaspberryPi.org telling you how to update your packages. The following caught my attention:

[Updating and upgrading Raspberry Pi OS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/updating.md)

> However, there are occasional changes made in the Foundation's Raspberry Pi OS image that require manual intervention, for example a newly introduced package. These are not installed with an upgrade, as this command only updates the packages you already have installed.

My question is simply; Where are these new packages listed? Once I know what they are called I can work out if I have them or not (The SD card came pre-loaded) or if I still need to install them.

Comment: Please add the url to the page you are referring to.

Comment: What version of the RaspiOS comes with your Raspberry Pi? Is it version Buster? Or what version do you want to upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method of determining new packages which are added.

The Foundation Blog usually advises any packages added to distributions and instructions for installing them.

These are infrequent.
There were 4 for Buster, nothing of enormous significance.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/latest-raspberry-pi-os-update-may-2020/    29th May 2020
https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/a-new-raspbian-update/  7th Feb 2020
https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/scratch-3-desktop-for-raspbian-on-raspberry-pi/    16th Aug 2019
https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/buster-the-new-version-of-raspbian/    25th Jun 2019

Comment: Thank you. So it's just trawling the blog for info. Hmmm... better than nothing I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Show installed packages

```
apt list --installed
```

To show all available packages, installed or not

```
apt list
```

You could also use `apt-cache pkgnames` , `dpkg-query -l` and some others that I have forgot.

More details about `apt` , https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-apt-command/

Comment: Ahh... I was hoping there was a list of what packages have been added to the OS distribution that aren't automatically added with an update. The packages that you'd get with a fresh image rather than a list of every package out there... or am I missing something...

Comment: @Eewec There is a list with packages that you'd get with a fresh image.